# Can't access values when mapping over in next.js / react

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, next.js

Hi I have some json which I'm having trouble accessing specific values in. Here is the code which is erroring:

```
 const Index = props => (
 <Layout>
 <h1>Case Studies</h1>

 <ul>
   {props.caseStudies.map(({ caseStudy }) => (
     <a>{caseStudy.title}</a>
   ))}
 </ul>

</Layout>
);
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

However if I remove:

```
{caseStudy.title}
```

for the above codeblock I can see in the React Inspector tools in Chrome that "caseStudies" is a prop of Index. And "title" is a key within the caseStudies prop. I just can't seem to access it!

Here is the offending json:

```
{
"status": "ok",
"sets": {
    "caseStudies": [
        {
        "_id": "1",
        "title": "Case Study Item One",
        "_title": "Case Study Item One",
        "date": "2018-06-01"
        }
    ]
 }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit wrong:

```
<ul>
  {props.caseStudies.map((caseStudy ) => (   // note the removed {}
    <a>{caseStudy.title}</a>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: So it was. Odd as that's what it has in the offical Next docs:- https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/fetching-data-for-pages/fetching-batman-shows

Comment: It's not that you can't use that syntax, it just depends what you're mapping over. For example on that tutorial page, `show` is the name of an object stored within the `shows` array. By using `{show}` in curly braces, you make it easier to access that specific part of the array. It also makes it more explicit what you're doing.

Comment: @JossClassey hits the point. Javascript feels a bit weird for many developers who came across from other languages. For example `document.querySelectorAll('a.vip').map(....)` will not work due to `querySelectorAll()` will not return an array but a `NodeList`. At this point js has techniques like the `...` operator: `[...document.querySelectorAll('a.vip')].map` would work because now it is an array....Javascript. Hate it, Feel it, love it :D